# JavaScript confirm onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, confirm, onsubmit

I'm writing a Perl script that dynamically prints out an HTML page.

The page allows the user to choose one of four tasks by clicking a radio button on a form.

If the user clicks the radio button for the task "Clear the signup sheet", I'm supposed to provide a warning to the user. If the user clicks OK, the form submits. If the user clicks cancel, nothing happens.

I'm new to JavaScript, so I based my code of two examples from my teacher: one of a confirm method run onClick on a button and the other of an alert method run onSubmit on a form.

But apparently I don't understand what I'm doing because it's not working. The dialog box doesn't even pop up.

How would I do what I need to do?

The relevant part of my code (without the Perl print statements) currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation( ) {
    if (maint.mainttask.value == "clearsheet") {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all entries?');
        if (answer==true){
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
</script>
<form method='post' action='path removed' name=maint ONSUBMIT="return confirmation( )">
<table>
<tr><td><input type=radio name='mainttask' checked value='clearsheet'></td><td>Clear the signup sheet</td></tr>
```

Comment: what is maint.mainttask.value ?

Comment: I forgot a part of my code. I made an edit to the original post.

maint = the name of the form
mainttask = the name of radio button
value = getting the value of the radio button

At least that's what I think that's supposed to do, based off the example I was looking at.

Comment: Just some syntax notes: Always use `===` instead of `==` in Javascript. `name=maint` should be `name="maint"`. `ONSUBMIT` should be `onsubmit`. Maybe fixing that will help?

Comment: Copy your all html code dear.

Comment: You want the entire page, not just the relevant stuff? There is a lot more.

Comment: On a side note, you can replace that entire `if (answer==true) { . . .` if-else section with `return answer;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation( )
{
    if (maint.mainttask.value == "clearsheet")
    {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all entries?');
        if (answer){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<form method='post' action='#' name='maint' ONSUBMIT="return confirmation( )">
<table>
<tr><td><input type=radio name='mainttask' checked value='clearsheet'></td><td>Clear the signup sheet</td></tr>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

**Try this edited code , hope now it will work for you and display confirmation box.**

Comment: So you want me to do this just to test it? If so, I just did, and even with changing it to document.maint.mainttask.value, nothing happens.

Comment: but if you will not add proper code then how we will help you dear ?

Comment: Just check my code you will get idea , name='maint' and i have add input time submit for my test. i think u have already submit type in your code.

Comment: Also action='path removed' , set your action link as per your requirement.

Comment: I just tried it. I had a dialog box pop up that said "undefined" and when I clicked ok on the dialog box, it cleared the sheet anyway.

Comment: try this if (answer){return true;}else{return false;}

Comment: When I originally tried your edited code, there was still the alert method, but I see that's gone now. Without that, I'm back to getting no dialog box.

Comment: ohhh my goddddd...cant understand what happening , in my localhost its working fine , but dont know why ur code not working.

Comment: Hmm... well, thanks for trying to help. I'll just ask my teacher in class.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use a standard button and call the submit() method from within the validation function rather than relying on a submit button and the onsubmit event. Others may disagree but in my view you have more control over things that way. Try the following...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
    if (maint.mainttask.value == "clearsheet") {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all entries?');
        if (answer==true){
            document.forms["maint"].submit();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<form method='post' action='path removed' name='maint'>
<table>
<tr><td><input type='radio' name='mainttask' checked value='clearsheet'></td><td>Clear the signup sheet<br />
<input type="button" onClick="confirmation()" value="Click me..."/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```